# How do you cancel a webview loading a web site?

Tags: java, javafx, webview, javafx-webengine

What I'm trying to implement is essentially the cancel button of a browser but using JavaFX's webview. This is the code I have so far:

```
Worker<Void> loadWorker = webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker();
if (loadWorker != null) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> loadWorker.cancel());
}
```

but it sometimes work and sometimes doesn't.

What's the proper way of canceling the webview/webengine task of loading a page?

Answer (score 2):

After canceling the `webEngine` task, can you try with setting the content of the `webEngine` to `null` :

```
webView.getEngine().load(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

The table in the **[`WebEngine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html)** states the *JavaScript user interface methods and properties with their corresponding WebEngine callbacks.*

Where `window.close()` corresponds to the `onVisibilityChanged` callback of the `WebEngine`.

---

A quick way to try out, in that case, could be :

```
webEngine.getOnVisibilityChanged().handle(closeWindowEvent); //event definition below
```

followed by a

```
webEngine.executeScript("window.close()");
```

---

Another way in which you make sure the window is closed is to define an event which could be dispatched by the **[`WebView's EventDispatcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#getEventDispatcher--)** for the current node.

```
// Here the event to be dispatched for closing the window shall be 
WebEvent<Boolean> closeWindowEvent = new WebEvent<>(webEngine, VISIBILITY_CHANGED, Boolean.FALSE);

webView.getEventDispatcher().dispatchEvent(closeWindowEvent, null); // no further events
```

---

In case of trying to cancel loading the web page only, you can make use of the `executeScript` to do:

```
webEngine.executeScript("window.stop()");
```

Comment: I'm not trying to close a Window, just cancelling the loading of a web page.

Comment: @Pablo `window.stop()` shall help you there in that case...?

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().cancel()
```

is your boy